# User Input as Variable and Text R

Tags: r

Let's say I want a function where a user inputs a word, which is the name of a variable, and then the function outputs the stored number for the variable along with the string for the variable. How can I do this?

Example:

```
chicago <- 30

fun <- function(){
  a <- readline("What City?")

}

fun()
```

And it would output:
"Chicago 30"

Comment: It's possible but this sounds like terrible design though. What is your overall goal.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I make sure that the input city name is lower case, like the variable name, and I `get` the value stored in that variable. I paste this together with the original string.

```
chicago <- 30

fun <- function(){
  a <- readline("What city?\n")
  paste(a, get(tolower(a)), sep = " ")
}
```

Running it looks something like this:

```
fun()

What city?
Chicago
[1] "Chicago 30"
```

Comment: Is get the key function that pulls the "30" using Chicago? I tried this in R and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "didn't work"? Did you get an error? Incorrect output? What output did you get? The code above runs fine for me.